# Null pointer exception when calling startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, start-activity

I'm having a problem (Null Pointer Exception) when calling startActivityForResult() from class inside another class, here is the code :

```
public class OCRActivity extends Activity {

public OCRActivity(String operator)
{
    this.operator = operator;
}


public void startCameraActivity() {

    final Intent capture_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(capture_intent, 1); // I get the Null pointer Exception here
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == 1){
            //get the Uri for the captured image
            picUri = data.getData();
            //carry out the crop operation
            performCrop();
        }
}
```

and here is where I call `startCameraActivity()`

```
public class WayToFillActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.way_to_fill);

    CAMERA_BTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_btn);
    CAMERA_BTN.setOnClickListener(this);
    Intent operator_intent =  getIntent();
    OPERATOR = operator_intent.getStringExtra("operator");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.camera_btn)
    {
        OCRActivity ocr = new OCRActivity(OPERATOR);
        ocr.startCameraActivity();

    }

}
```

So please tell me if I'm doing something wrong !!

The Logcat

```
01-13 16:22:26.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32425): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 16:22:26.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32425):    at     android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
01-13 16:22:26.583: E/AndroidRuntime(32425):    at com.almannaa.EasyRecharge.OCRActivity.startCameraActivity(OCRActivity.java:176)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat..

Comment: You don't instantiate activities via constructor. Also, I don't see why you don't launch the camera capture Intent from your `WayToFillActivity`

Comment: the OCRActivity class is too big and have alot of methods, i just get where the error is

Comment: You should not be extending Activity in OCRActivity, or if you did this deliberately, then you should not instantiate an instance of it directly and it should have all of the overrides required of an Activity (onCreate etc)

Comment: OnCreate() is exist but I didn't copy it

Comment: Then you are getting confused about classes and extending them. The only way you should ever start an Activity is through an intent, either from Android (the launcher or another app) or from your own code. `OCRActivity ocr = new OCRActivity(OPERATOR)` is an error.  You should think again about the design and how your Activities relate to each other.

Comment: @Simon yes you are right, I get confused  cause I didn't work on android for too long. I got it now, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are treating `OCRActivity` as an ordinary Java class, and not like another Activity. Due to this, when you call `startActivityForResult()` you get a NPE as the Activity's `onCreate()` has not been called, which means that its current instance is not valid for calling `startActivityForResult()`

Instead, try using:

```
public class WayToFillActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.way_to_fill);

    CAMERA_BTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_btn);
    CAMERA_BTN.setOnClickListener(this);
    Intent operator_intent =  getIntent();
    OPERATOR = operator_intent.getStringExtra("operator");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.camera_btn)
    {
        OCRActivity ocr = new OCRActivity(OPERATOR);
        ocr.startCameraActivity();

    }

}

public void startCameraActivity() {

    final Intent capture_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(capture_intent, 1); // I get the Null pointer Exception here
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == 1){
            //get the Uri for the captured image
            picUri = data.getData();
            //carry out the crop operation
            performCrop();
        }
}
}
```

You should probably move functions like `performCrop()` (and any other functions that don't really need to be in the activity itself, and can work by receiving data as parameters and returning it) into a separate class (call it Utility or whatever).

Comment: You mean get all the methode I want from the OCRActivity class to WayToFillActivity class ?? But also `performCrop()` is startActivityForResult

Comment: Yes, that would work too. But it would be terrible class design. I have no idea what you mean by `But also performCrop() is startActivityForResult`.

Comment: inside performCrop() method there is `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: I got it, I changed the way how I call the methods. It's wrong to create object of activity inside another activity. that's why it ain't work thanks for help

Comment: @FirasAlMannaa Your last comment has helped me. I was stuck here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if the data is not null.

```
@Override        
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //get the Uri for the captured image
            picUri = data.getData();
            //carry out the crop operation
            performCrop();
        } }
```

Comment: the Exception happened before getting to `onActivityResult`